# program to access files on internal hard drive, windows

Tags: command-line, hard-drive, 15.10, directory

I would like a script that will rename the file Utilman.exe in Windows/System32 to NotUtilman.exe and renames cmd.exe to Utilman.exe . I am not asking for the full script, I am new (-ish) to Ubuntu, and I do not know how to access files on another drive, but i know that C:/Windows/System32/ will not work. I do not know  how to access those files with the command line, (the script) and would like help on this.
I am running Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: How many Windows 7+ users do you have getting locked out? Or are you just trying to hack into library stations?

Comment: Don't judge my morals, I just want admin accnt at school

Comment: and i hate having to manual rename the files

Comment: Like Glitkch's answer starts, I'd say it's more trouble than it's worth. Every drive is going to be different, which means you'd either have to change the drive in the script each time it's run, or you'd have to put an option in to record the drive name you input, which isn't the easiest thing to do. Like he said, unless you doing this multiple times (for the work it'll take, I'd say more than 10 daily), it's going to be A LOT easier to just change the filenames manually. Also, since you'll be doing this off a LiveUSB, you'll have to make it persistent to even save your script, which is tricky

Comment: Just do it manually.

Comment: oh my god.... The reason I am not doing it manualy is because i get tired of doing it every day!

Comment: @Zacharee1 The second one, but at school

Answer (score 2):

G'day Ty,

This doesn't sound like something you'd need a script for, unless you were intending on repeating the action multiple times (say, more than twice).  Anything less would just be creating more work and possible points of failure.  To write a script would require more in-depth knowledge of exactly how your computer and drives are set up, or would have to make assumptions which may be incorrect.  I hope you don't mind if I give you step-by-step instead.  I've also provided the rough commandline equivalents to each step.

To accomplish what you're asking, your main steps would appear to be:

- mounting the correct partition read/write
- renaming the relevant files
- saving changes/unmounting (ensuring writes-to-disk)

If you are using Ubuntu on one drive, and the windows drive is physically separate, then it's likely (but not definite) that your Ubuntu drive will be referenced as /dev/sda, and the Windows drive as /dev/sdb.  You can do most (if not all) of what you want in GUI programs though.

## Manual Steps

Firstly, you'll want to open the Disk Utility (see https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-partitions.html) - you should be able to find this easily enough by simply typing 'disk' into the Dash.

This will present you with a graphical representation of your disks (including hard drives), and from here you should be able to get the mounting part sorted.

Find your Windows partition (this will be easier if it's labelled or you recognise the approximate size), and try clicking it to select it, then click the little play symbol that shows up on it.  That will attempt to mount the partition.  If it works, it'll give you a text link you can click, to open that location where it's been mounted to, in your default file manager.  If that's successful, you can skip the next two paragraphs.

If it doesn't work, and brings up an error about the filesystem being 'unclean', 'not safely shut down', or 'hibernation file present', we'll need to go through an additional step or two in order to get the partition mounted properly so that you can make changes.

For any of the above errors, one workaround is to boot into Windows 10, press Win+R, type "shutdown /s /t 0" into the Run box and press Enter.  This should execute a *proper* shut down, rather than hibernation or 'hybrid shutdown' which causes such problems.

Once you've got a Windows partition that can be mounted writeable without errors, you can navigate to the drive using the handy link provided by the Disk Utility, saunter on into your Windows folder, and make your changes.  You can rename files by right-clicking them and choosing Rename, or by pressing the F2 key when they're selected.

Once you're done, you can use 'Eject' or 'Unmount' in the right-click menu on that drive, in the left hand pane of the file manager, or return to Disk Utility and use the Stop icon for that partition there.

If you run into any bumps along this road, just post back whatever information you have on the new problem, and I'll endeavour to assist you further :)

## Command line equivalents

List all drives and their partitions: `sudo fdisk -l`

This should allow you to work out which partition is your Windows one, based on size - you can also use the Disk Utility to determine this information to use in your scripts, as the /dev/sdX-style enumeration is displayed underneath when you select a partition in the interface.  I'll assume /dev/sdb2 for the following instructions.

Create a location at which to mount your Windows partition: `sudo mkdir -p /mnt/win`

The -p parameter is used to avoid errors if the destination already exists (but will still show any other relevant errors).

Attempt to mount the Windows partition, letting the system do all the guesswork: `sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/win`

If this fails, attempt mounting with some typical options: `sudo mount -t ntfs -o defaults,locale=en_US.utf8,rw /dev/sdb2 /mnt/win`

Change to the relevant folder: `cd /mnt/win/Windows/System32`

(case matters, though you can use the Tab key for auto-completion after you've typed the first couple of letters of each folder)

Rename the files in question: `mv Utilman.exe Utilman.bak`

Then `cp cmd.exe Utilman.exe`

Unmount the partition to ensure changes are saved: `umount /mnt/win`

If you use a mount point under /media (e.g, /media/ty/win) then your file manager should also have the partition show up in its sidebar - but again, to script this we'd need to know more information (in this case, your username).

If you need further clarification please let me know.

Comment: Yes, I have a need to do this action multiple actions (Please don't ask) and all I really need is how to access a separate drive via command line. Thank you for your answer though. So I would just, say, to move to that drive, type

Comment: and type    cd /dev/sdb ?

Comment: I will update the answer above to explain the commandlines being used 'behind the scenes' at each step.

Comment: I've updated as promised.                    
                
No, it won't be /dev/sdb, as that would refer to an entire drive.  Modern Windows installs automatically create a small boot/system partition (which would be /dev/sdb1) making the main Windows partition (what you see as the C: drive) usually /dev/sdb2.

If you have more than two drives in your computer, it may be /dev/sdc2 or /dev/sdd2.  If you actually have Ubuntu and Windows running from the same drive, it may be /dev/sda2 or /dev/sda3 etc.  Either Disk Utility or the fdisk command should be able to clarify that point for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount the drive (assuming it's not already mounted) with

```
mkdir ~/Windows ; sudo mount /dev/sdb ~/Windows
```

From there you can run

```
cd ~/Windows
```

And you will have the filesystem from your windows machine.  Keep in mind, this filesystem can be finicky with some of the newer Windows versions.  You may have to enter the Windows OS and disable Quick Boot or Hibernation, depending on what version it is.  Simple way to shut down cleanly in Windows is

```
shutdown /s /t 0
```

That should perform a full shutdown in Windows.  Now you can `cd` and `mv` around just as if you were in Linux.  Just make sure you use `/` instead of `\` in filepaths.

Now. for my question to you: Why on earth are you trying to rename `Utilman.exe` and `cmd.exe`?  And why do you need to do this multiple times?  We here on Stack Exchange aren't just here to provide answers, we're here to help make sure you don't do something dangerous, irresponsible, or foolish.